# Adobe Air - Paste image via context menu

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

Is there a way to copy an image into an Air app through the context menu (right-click menu) or at least to detect if there is an image within the clipboard?

Thanks
Uli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One strategy would be to check the clipboard on the ACTIVATE event and do something like enable/disable a context menu item based on the result:

```
private function checkForImageData(e:Event):void {

  myContextMenu.clipboardItems.paste = Clipboard.generalClipboard.hasFormat(ClipboardFormats.BITMAP_FORMAT);

}

addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, checkForImageData);
```

Comment: Sorry, me again. Any ideas how to detect a **print screen** press? For some reasons **checkForImageData** and **KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN** not detecting that one.

Comment: @Uli - With a quick search, I found this article on [Print Screen Detection in AIR](http://www.psyked.co.uk/apollo/print-screen-detection-in-air.htm).  The author concludes there is no Keyboard support for it (ie, the PrtScr key does not trigger the KeyDown/Up event), and provides a polling based work around.  Since the Clipboard class does not implement IEventDispatcher, I don't really have any better suggestion.